Access Azure Storage from Azure VM without signing in
In AWS - We can access s3 buckets from an ec2 instance by create a role and attaching the IAM role to the EC2 instance. Then ec2 instance can access s3 bucket from the VM without ACCESSS_KEY and SECRET_KEY.
How can I achieve the same thing with Azure VM and Azure Storage? I want to use Azure CLI to access azure storage or other services but without logging in and instead use roles and attach it to the azure VM.

I believe you are able to create Managed Itentity for Azure VM and assign appropriate role to this Managed Identity
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-configure-managed-identities?pivots=qs-configure-portal-windows-vm
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal

Agree with Vadim Bondaruk, Managed identity can be used here, but still with managed identity in order to use Azure CLI, you need to login using the command az login --identity and then only you can perform storage accounts related activities considering managed identity has the required roles.
